# Rails date_select to generate a csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to export a CSV file of Newbie user email addresses. Newbies are users "created_at" after the date selected in the date_select tag (basically the most recent sign-ups).

I'm using the FasterCSV gem and [Scott Becker's code](http://synthesis.sbecker.net/articles/2007/06/07/how-to-generate-csv-files-in-rails), and borrowed the @start_date from [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4630) to implement in the method.

Here's what my controller looks like:

```
  def newbs_export
    @start_date = Date.civil(params[:range][:"start_date(1i)"].to_i, params[:range][:"start_date(2i)"].to_i, params[:range][:"start_date(3i)"].to_i)
    @users = User.find(:all, :if => [@created_at >= @start_date])

    csv_string = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
      # header row
      csv << ["email"]

      # data rows
      @users.each do |user|  
      #if user[:created_at] >= Time.now
        csv << [user.email]
      end

    end

    # send it to the browsah
    send_data csv_string,
              :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
              :disposition => "attachment; filename=newbs.csv"

  end
```

Here's my newbs.html.erb:

```
<% form_tag({:controller => "accounts", :action => "newbs_export"}, :method => "get") do %>
<%= date_select('range', 'start_date', :order => [:month, :day, :year])%>
<%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

I've mixed code and dug myself a bit of a hole trying to stitch different solutions together. Any advice on where I could go from here?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error/problem you are getting?

Comment: Sorry, Joshua... it was spitting a NilClass error at me. Maran hit it on the head though. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I will start with changing:

```
@users = User.find(:all, :if => [@created_at >= @start_date])
```

to

```
@users = User.where("created_at >= ?", @start_date)
```

For rails3 or

```
@users = User.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at >= ?", @start_date])
```

For rails2

If you post any other errors / problems you are having I will try to update this answer.